# Boundary behaviour for functions in $H_0(div;\Omega)$ and $H_0(curl;\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

I seen in *Evans* that for $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ where $\partial\Omega$ is $C^1$ then $u|_{\partial\Omega}=Tu=0$, that is, $u$ vanishes at the boundary.

In the question
"[How to prove $H_0^1(\Omega)=H_0(div;\Omega)\cap H_0(curl;\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303816/how-to-prove-h-01-omega-h-0div-omega-cap-h-0curl-omega)", the spaces $H_0(div;\Omega)$ and $H_0(curl;\Omega)$ are introduced. Here, $H_0(div;\Omega)$ is the closure of $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ in $H(div;\Omega):=\{u\in L_2(\Omega):div\,u\in L_2(\Omega)\}$ with respect to the norm $\|u\|=\|u\|_{L_2(\Omega)}+\|div\ u\|_{L_2(\Omega)}$. With $H_0(curl;\Omega)$ being defined analogously.

**My problem:** How does one see that $u\in H_0(div;\Omega)$ satisfies $u|_{\partial\Omega}\cdot n=0$ and that $v\in H_0(curl;\Omega)$ satisfies $v|_{\partial\Omega}\times n=0$?

Comment: The idea is to prove that $u\mapsto u|_{\partial\Omega}\cdot n$ is a continuous operator. For the $H(div)$ case this is done in the classical book by Temam ''NAVIER-STOKES EQUATIONS- THEORY AND NUMERICAL ANALYSIS" in the very first section.

Comment: I'll check this source out, thanks. Is there any other source you can recommend for the other identity (for $curl$)?

Comment: I'm just thinking about this ... much like for the $H_0^1$ case, is the idea for showing $u|_{\partial\Omega}\cdot n=0$ and $v|_{\partial\Omega}\times n=0$ that it is sufficient to consider for the behaviour for a sequence of text functions $(\psi)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $C_c^\infty(\Omega)$ or $C_c^\infty(\Omega)^3$ respectively? Then, if the respective trace is continuous, $0=0\cdot n=T\psi_n\to Tu$ and $0=0\times n=T\psi_n\to Tu$?

Comment: So that, it will be tantamount to the same proof/computation as in Evans?