# Is $H(div; \Omega ) \cap H(curl; \Omega )$ compactly embedd in $L^2(\Omega)$?

Tags: vector-spaces, sobolev-spaces, vector-fields, fractional-sobolev-spaces

I know a similar question says that [$H_0^1(\Omega)=H_0(div;\Omega)\cap H_0(curl;\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303816/how-to-prove-h-01-omega-h-0div-omega-cap-h-0curl-omega), which was shown in Lemma~ 2.5 of the book "Finite Elements Methods for Navier-Stokes Equations" by Girault and Raviart.  And $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is obviously compactly embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$. In the case of weakened boundary conditions, I know that there is such a conclusion ("$\hookrightarrow\hookrightarrow $" means compactly embedding)

$$
 H_0(div;\Omega)\cap H(curl;\Omega) \hookrightarrow\hookrightarrow L^2(\Omega)
$$
and
$$
 H(div;\Omega)\cap H_0(curl;\Omega) \hookrightarrow\hookrightarrow L^2(\Omega),
$$
which has been shown in Corollary 3.49 of the book "Finite Element Methods for Maxwell's Equations" by Peter Monk .

But I want to know, when the boundary conditions are completely removed, the space is still compact embedded in $L^2(\Omega)$ ? Associated graphic norm $\|\cdot\|^2_{V}:=\|\nabla\times\cdot\|^2+\|\nabla\cdot \cdot\|^2+\|\cdot\|^2$ on $V:=H(div;  \Omega ) \cap H(curl;  \Omega )$, can we get the following results?

$$V \hookrightarrow\hookrightarrow   L^2(\Omega).$$